# Alsamixer is not loaded

Tags: alsa

How do I load alsamixer? How do I know if I am added to audio group? I am really new to the whole command line so be as specific as possible please.

Answer (score 0):

To open the alsa mixer control panel, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo alsamixer
```

To check if a user is added to a certain group, run the command

```
groups <username>
```

To add a user to a group, use the following command

```
sudo adduser username groupname
```

Comment: @user67946, Did this answer your question?

Comment: [We should not be in the `audio` group](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/PerfectSetup)